# select a column from a table only if the count of another column is greater than zero

Tags: sql, hive

Im currently struggeling with a hive sql statement. I have the following schema

```
ID | DESCRIPTION | BRAND | RATING
---------------------------------
1  | one         | A     | 0
---------------------------------
2  | two         | A     | 0
---------------------------------
3  | three       | B     | 0
---------------------------------
4  | four        | B     | 1
---------------------------------
5  | five        | C     | 1
---------------------------------
```

I want to select the distinct brand but only if the count of the column rating where the rating is equal to zero is greater than zero. The query im searching for should return the following result for the dataset given above:

```
A, B
```

- It returns A because A has at least one rating equals zero.
- It returns B because B has at least one rating equals zero.
- It does not return C because C has not a single rating equals zero.

When I do a distinct select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BRAND FROM MY_TABLE ....
```

I have no idea how to access the brand of the current row so that I can use it in a subselect to do a count, something like:

```
.... WHERE COUNT(SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE RATING = 0 AND BRAND = "CURRENT BRAND") > 0
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT BRAND FROM MY_TABLE where rating = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select brand
from my_table
where rating = 0
group by brand;
```

Or, more simply:

```
select distinct brand
from my_table
where rating = 0;
```